# Is there anyway to load a UILabel with text from a webpage?

Tags: html, ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uilabel

Is there anyway to load a UILabel with text from a webpage?  If I define a webpage is there anyway I can take text off of the page?

Like if in the source of the page says "9.5000/9.5009" can I take the "9.5000/9.5009" and make it the text of a label, even if that number changes is there a way to load it by using the declared "Rate"?  Or am I wrong about it being declared as "Rate".

Could I use code like:

```
#define kLatestKivaLoansURL @"http://www.roblox.com/Marketplace/TradeCurrency.aspx"

NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSArray* latestLoans = [(NSDictionary*)[responseString JSONValue] objectForKey:@"Rate"];
NSDictionary* loan = [latestLoans objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* rate = [loan objectForKey:@"Rate"];
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",rate];
```

Is there any way to do this without a page outputting JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/rateScript.php"];
NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
label.text=response;
[response release];
```

using the following as the script:

```
<?php
$ratefile=file_get_contents("http://www.roblox.com/Marketplace/TradeCurrency.aspx");
$position=0;
$position=strpos($ratefile, '"Rate"',$position)+7;
$start=strpos($ratefile, '"Rate"',$position)+7;
$end=strpos($ratefile, '<',$start+1);
echo substr($ratefile,$start,$end-$start);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know if there is any way to do this without a page outputting JSON?

Comment: you could make a php scraper to find the piece of data you want and then just have `NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/scraper.php"];
NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
label.text=response;`